# Error in Next.js - "JSX Namespace is disabled by default because react does not support it yet. ..."

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jsx

I'm trying to import React components generated via Webflow Devlink into a Next.js application. (Based on these resources: https://docs.developers.webflow.com/docs/devlink-documentation-and-usage-guide, https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app)

Some of the components I create in Webflow and export to the react application trigger errors similar to this one:

```
Error: 
  × JSX Namespace is disabled by default because react does not support it yet. You can specify jsc.transform.react.throwIfNamespace to false to override default behavior
    ╭─[C:\Entwicklung\nextjs-dashboard\devlink\ProductItem.js:5:1]
  5 │     
  6 │     export function ProductItem({ as: _Component = _Builtin.Block }) {
  7 │       return (
  8 │ ╭─▶     <_Component
  9 │ │         className={_utils.cx(_styles, "product2_item")}
 10 │ │         tag="div"
 11 │ │         th:each="process: ${processes}"
 12 │ │       >
 13 │ │         <_Builtin.Block
 14 │ │           className={_utils.cx(_styles, "margin-bottom", "margin-xsmall")}
 15 │ │           tag="div"
 16 │ │         >
 17 │ │           <_Builtin.Link
 18 │ │             className={_utils.cx(_styles, "product2_image-link")}
 19 │ │             button={false}
 20 │ │             block="inline"
 21 │ │             options={{
 22 │ │               href: "#",
 23 │ │             }}
 24 │ │           >
 25 │ │             <_Builtin.Block
 26 │ │               className={_utils.cx(_styles, "", "product2_image-wrapper")}
 27 │ │               tag="div"
 28 │ │             >
 29 │ │               <_Builtin.Image
 30 │ │                 className={_utils.cx(_styles, "product2_image")}
 31 │ │                 height="auto"
 32 │ │                 loading="lazy"
 33 │ │                 width="auto"
 34 │ │                 th:src="${process.imageUrl}"
 35 │ │                 alt=""
 36 │ │                 src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/659fa5720bf59a09e14c4805/659fa5720bf59a09e14c4825_csm_HC_AIR_ab67dab274.jpg"
 37 │ │               />
 38 │ │             </_Builtin.Block>
 39 │ │           </_Builtin.Link>
 40 │ │         </_Builtin.Block>
 41 │ │         <_Builtin.Block
 42 │ │           className={_utils.cx(_styles, "margin-bottom", "margin-xsmall")}
 43 │ │           tag="div"
 44 │ │         >
 45 │ │           <_Builtin.Link
 46 │ │             className={_utils.cx(_styles, "product2_text-link")}
 47 │ │             button={false}
 48 │ │             block="inline"
 49 │ │             options={{
 50 │ │               href: "#",
 51 │ │             }}
 52 │ │           >
 53 │ │             <_Builtin.Block
 54 │ │               className={_utils.cx(_styles, "product2_left")}
 55 │ │               tag="div"
 56 │ │             >
 57 │ │               <_Builtin.Block
 58 │ │                 className={_utils.cx(
 59 │ │                   _styles,
 60 │ │                   "text-size-medium",
 61 │ │                   "text-weight-semibold"
 62 │ │                 )}
 63 │ │                 tag="div"
 64 │ │                 th:text="${process.name}"
 65 │ │               >
 66 │ │                 {"HC. AIR"}
 67 │ │                 <br />
 68 │ │                 {""}
 69 │ │               </_Builtin.Block>
 70 │ │             </_Builtin.Block>
 71 │ │           </_Builtin.Link>
 72 │ │         </_Builtin.Block>
 73 │ │         <_Builtin.Block
 74 │ │           className={_utils.cx(_styles, "margin-top-auto")}
 75 │ │           tag="div"
 76 │ │         >
 77 │ │           <_Builtin.Link
 78 │ │             className={_utils.cx(
 79 │ │               _styles,
 80 │ │               "button",
 81 │ │               "is-secondary",
 82 │ │               "is-small",
 83 │ │               "max-width-full"
 84 │ │             )}
 85 │ │             button={true}
 86 │ │             th:href="@{/executions/execute/${step.stepId}}"
 87 │ │             block=""
 88 │ │             options={{
 89 │ │               href: "#",
 90 │ │             }}
 91 │ │           >
 92 │ │             {"Ausführen"}
 93 │ │           </_Builtin.Link>
 94 │ │         </_Builtin.Block>
 95 │ ╰─▶     </_Component>
 96 │       );
 97 │     }
    ╰────
```

A quick google research suggests that I'd need to add
`'use client';`
at the top of my (I guess) component? I tried doing so but don't seem to be able to make it work.